# Rearrange multiple columns on sheet with Google script

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vba

I am trying to convert a VBA macro that rearranges columns on a sheet from an array of column indices to a Google script

I want to return all columns but with the columns listed in the array as the first 3 columns and all the other columns in their same order

The original vba is using header names but I am using column indices

I get error `Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 24`

I have no idea if there are other issues as well

Thanks in advance

Here is what I have

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var LC = sheet.getLastColumn();
var LR = sheet.getLastRow();

var headers = [4,2,3]; //array of colunm indices
var temp = [];

var Dex = 0
for (var i = 0; i < LC; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < LC; j++) { 
    for (var F = 0; F < headers.length - 1; F++) {
      if (headers[F] = data[j]) {
           Dex = F
           break;
       };
     }

      if (F < i) {
         temp = data.indexOf(i);
         data[i] = data.indexOf(j)
         data[j] = temp
        }
    };
   };

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, LC,LR).setValues([data])
}
```

Here is the vba

```
Sub vba()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim Temp
Dim nams As Variant
Dim F
Dim Dex As Integer

nams = Array("ItemID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Year")
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    For J = i To rng.Columns.Count
        For F = 0 To UBound(nams)
            If nams(F) = rng(J) Then Dex = F: Exit For
        Next F
        If F < i Then
            Temp = rng.Columns(i).Value
            rng(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Columns(J).Value
            rng(J).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = Temp
        End If
    Next J
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this:

```
function moveColumns() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements");
  var rg= sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=[];
  var first3 = [8,7,6,5];
  var first3desc=first3.slice();
  first3desc.sort(function(a, b){return b-a;});
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var row=vA[i];
    for(var j=0;j<first3.length;j++){
      row.splice(j,0,vA[i][first3[j]-1+j]);
    }
    for(var j=0;j<first3desc.length;j++){
      var c=first3desc[j]-1+first3.length;//for debugging
      row.splice(first3desc[j]-1+first3.length,1);
    }
    vB.push(row);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}
```

Here's the function as I run it this time.

```
function moveColumns() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements");
  var rg= sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=[];
  var first3 = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
  var first3desc=first3.slice();
  first3desc.sort(function(a, b){return b-a;});
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var row=vA[i];
    for(var j=0;j<first3.length;j++){
      row.splice(j,0,vA[i][first3[j]-1+j]);
    }
    for(var j=0;j<first3desc.length;j++){
      var c=first3desc[j]-1+first3.length;
      row.splice(first3desc[j]-1+first3.length,1);
    }
    vB.push(row);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}
```

My "Elements" sheet before:

[image]

My "Elements" sheet after:

[image]

Comment: Cooper thanks for the response, I copied your code and made the loop replacement.  The code ran without error but nothing changed i.e no columns were moved.  If I understand your code at all I think the 2nd loop is removing the wrong columns? I tried to fix it but no luck

Comment: `I assumed that the numbers in first3 array are column numbers starting from 1` Yes correct.  This might be more telling if  `first3 = [5,4,1]` so after running function I should get `Col1 >> Col5`,  `Col2 >> Col4` and   
 `Col3 >> Col1` but after I cun the function nothing changes.  Am I miss-understanding something

Comment: I did find an error in the second loop.  Try it again.  And I changed the sheet name

Comment: Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

data gets a 2D array, but later the script handled it as 1D array. In other words, to reference a cell value, instead of `data[index]` use something like `data[row][column]`.

A single equal sign `=` is use to assign an object/literal to a variable so this `headers[F] = data[j]` instead of doing a comparison replaces the value of `headers[F]` by the object of `data[j]` which initially is an array.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I will see if I can get somewhere from your comments